# UIStackView Layout

Tags: swift, uibutton, xcode7, ios9, uistackview

I would like to have two `UIButtons` side by side in a `UIStackView` both at 50% of the view. When I drag two buttons into the Stack View, the first one takes up the majority of the view and the other is the smallest width it can be. 
Should I be doing something else?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are doing right, but you may missed to do below thing.

You need to set the `UIStackViewDistribution` & `UIStackViewAlignment` property as per your need.

The `distribution` property determines the layout of the arranged views along the stack’s axis.

The `alignment` property determines the layout of the arranged views perpendicular to the stack’s axis.

Refer [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStackView_Class_Reference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIStackViewDistribution) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your `UIStackViewDistribution` property to `Fill Equally` to get the 50/50 distribution.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need additionally add constraint that buttonA.width = buttonB.width.